# Bash script for monitor files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

scenario is -

In the **Location /opt/data/** there are **10 difference files** with **name ending with previous day**
eg - **file_1_20160627**

I need to check whether these 10 files exist or not.

If one exists, I need to **show output - "OK - file_1_20160627 exist"** and **write output in /tmp/report.txt file**

If a file does not exist, I want the same as above - **"Failed - file_1_20160627 not exist"** and **write output in the same /tmp/report.txt file**

Every day when the script runs, **content on that file must replace.**

I tried to write but I'm not good in scripting. below script only for 4 files. I think so many things need to be change.

appreciate someone help me to create this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
time=`date +%H%M`
week=`date +%a`


/bin/rm -f /tmp/report.txt

if [ "$time" -ge 1300 ] && [ $time -lt 2359 ]; then
if [ "$week" == Sun ]; then

                if [ -f "find /opt/data/ -type f -name "file_1_`date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d`.txt"" ];
                then
                   echo "OK - file_1 file does exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                else
                   echo "Failed - file_1 file does not exist." >> /tmp/report.txt

                fi

                if [ -f "find /opt/data/ -type f -name "file_2_`date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d`.txt"" ];
                then
                   echo "OK - file_2 file exist." >> /tmp/report.txt
                else
                   echo "Failed - file_2 file does not exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                fi
        else

        fi

                if [ -f "find /opt/data/ -type f -name "file_3_`date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d`.txt"" ];
                then
                   echo "OK - file_3 file exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                else
                   echo "Failed - file_3 file does not exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                fi

                if [ -f "find /opt/data/ -type f -name "file_4_`date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d`.txt"" ];
                then
                   echo "OK - file_4 file exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                else
                   echo "Failed - file_4 file does not exist" >> /tmp/report.txt
                fi
        else

        fi
```

Comment: What *specifically* do you need help with? We're not going to write the whole script for you. What particular part are you stuck on?

Comment: actually looping part is little bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PREFIX="/opt/data"
REPORT="/tmp/report.txt"
DATE=$( date +%Y%m%d )

rm "$REPORT"

for i in `seq 1 10`;
    do

            FILENAME="file_${i}_${DATE}"
            FULLFN="$PREFIX/$FILENAME"
            if [ -f "$FULLFN" ]; then
                    echo "OK - $FILENAME exists" >> $REPORT
            else
                    echo "Failed - $FILENAME do not exist" >> $REPORT
            fi
    done
```

Comment: You forgot to delete the report before you start appending.

Comment: @RedX answer updated, thanks!

Comment: and you dont use the date from day before :)

Comment: @nouseforname you're right... I hope the script is at least a good starting point :)

Comment: @Lino thanks for the script. I changed my script according to yours script. my expectation 85% complete but the date in the file name should be need to change to previous day's date.

Comment: To get yesterday's date do this: DATE=$(date -d "-1 day" "+%Y%m%d")